Why is potential continuous at dielectric conjunction?
Lets take for an example, a spherical capacitor with two dielectrics. The Electric Field will then be given by $$\frac{Q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0\varepsilon_r r^{2}}$$

We know that then the electric field will "jump" at boundary from $\varepsilon_1$ to $\varepsilon_2$ due to the value of $\varepsilon$ changing in the denominator. Next we also know that taking the Path integral of the electric field (without integration limits) will give us the formula for the potential. $$\int_{}^{}E.dr = \frac{Q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0\varepsilon_r r} + C$$
Here the formula is still dependent on the permittivity $\varepsilon$, so why is the potential considered to be continuos at dielectric Boundaries?

$\dots$ the electric field will "jump" at boundary $\dots$
This means that the potential gradient will change at the boundary but that does not mean that the potential changes.
Thus a graph of potential against position will have a change of gradient at a boundary but no change in potential.

A dielectric without free charges is neutral macroscopically. The continuity of the potential at the common surface of two different dielectrics is a consequence of the absence of free charges at the interface.  Not only the potential is continuous but so are the normal component of the D vector and the tangential component of the E vector, as well.
In contrast, the normal component of the E field has a jump because of the continuity of  the D field: $D_{n1}=\epsilon_1 E_{n2}=\epsilon_1 E_{n2}=D_{n2}.$ (In the spherical example the normals are in the radial directions.) Despite this when you calculate the potential drop across the interface by integrating the electric field vector over a path that is normal to that interface you still get a continuous function just as the integral of a step function is continuous with a kink that is a jump in its slope.

Even an interface charge leaves the potential continuous.

@my2cts I was careful to assume no free charges only as a sufficient condition and avoided the issue of necessity. Otherwise, the question of moveable charges may come up and then it gets complicated by the chemical potential. For example, at the junction of different metals you get the continuity of the electrochemical potential but the electrostatic potential has a jump.

You're absolutely right. I was only thinking about the dielectrics of the interface. The chemistry causes a discontinuity in the potential.

@my2cts I cannot describe to you what a "devastating" experience was to have learned in college that "chemistry", you know the stuff that strange people in white coats and stinky labs are doing, beats Gauss's law...

I think that it is rarely, if ever, questions of this sort are asking for a consideration of chemical potential.

@hyportnex Equally devastating is how much better quantum chemists are at solving the Schrödinger and the Dirac equation than physicists.
